# Using Group By & Returning the latest duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 5 columns in the table, `id, address, lat, lng, timesetamp` and a row is considered a duplicate when both rows have similar values in `lat` and `lng` columns.

**MySQL Query**

`SELECT address, lat, lng FROM table GROUP BY lat, lng`

**Problem:** I managed to get it to return only unique rows with this query. However the result appear to be the duplicate row that was inserted into the database the earliest. How can I make MySQL return the latest duplicated row? Something like return the duplicated row with the latest `timestamp`

Comment: What means similar ? Can you post an example result set ?

Comment: `(Funny st, 41.0, 80.1)` and `(Haha st, 41.0, 80.1)` are similar, while `(Funny st, 41.0, 80.1)` and `(Funny st, 41.0, 9.9)` are not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get the row with the latest timestamp for each lat/long combination regardless of how many rows of each combination there are.

```
SELECT
    [what you want to know about the latest row]
FROM
    table t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            lat,
            long,
            max(timestamp) as latest
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY
            lat,
            long
     ) as t2
     ON (
         t1.lat=t2.lat AND
         t1.long=t2.long AND
         t1.timestamp=t2.latest
     )
```

If you only want rows that have duplicate combinations you will need to adjust the sub-query to count the GROUPed rows and use HAVING to filter them.

Comment: I tried your method on a table with 1500 rows, and it took much faster to execute

Comment: Not sure if you change the accepted answer but if mine worked better for you it might be helpful to make mine the accepted answer for future reference ;-)

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
SELECT address, lat, lng FROM table where timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from table GROUP BY lat, lng)
```

EDIT:

here is the nested query. the sub query will return the max timestamp and it's based on the group by lat and lng field so it will return the multiple result so you need to used in() function. And the outer query will retrieve the value based on the timestamp, suppose there was multiple timestamp for different lat,lng you got then these query will giving all those records.

if any confusion asked

Comment: How does the `IN` clause work? It is difficult to google for the `IN` clause as it is a stop word. Why not use `=` instead of `IN`

Comment: suppose you want multiple like 1,10,13 etc. this was the Id then you can define in in() similar there is many function are available like any(), notin() etc in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html

Comment: I noticed that this increased the query time tremendously, adding the subquery increased the time from <1sec to 30sec. Is this normal?

Comment: when we used the in() it getting time so I think you need join query

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this in a two step process.  Get the list that has more than 1 record by using the

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then from that list get a second list of records with the latest timestamp.